# Migrating multi currency data to another org where Multi currency is not enabled

Tags: multi-currency, data-migration

We are migrating data(Account,Contact,Opportunity,Product,Pricebook,LineItems) from one org to another org.

Source org has multi currency enabled where as target org has not as it uses only USD. We are not planning to enable it in target org as customer needs all revenue calculation and reporting in USD. So when we move data, do we have to export, convert amount field values of different currencies into USD using exchange rates and then import? Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: If your org currency in source org having multi currency same as currency in target org i.e. USD?

Comment: @manjit5190 Source org is using multiple currency and not just USD